# Problem with SQL bulk insert tab delimited file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, flat-file

I am having a problem with using bulk insert. The issue is that the source files (tab delimited) that I'm dealing with contain rows that end in `cr/lf` without filling in values of the empty columns with tab for the rest of the row. So when the data is pulled into SQL Server, it's combining those shortened lines into the previous line. so basically it's combining multiple rows into one rather than writing it as two separate rows with nulls at the end of the first row.

Example to illustrate the problem: sample .txt file

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
1   2   3   4   5
2   5   4   6
4   4   6   4   
4   5   6   4   6
```

SQL to create table and bulk insert

```
CREATE TABLE test (
[column1] varchar(MAX) NULL,
[column2] varchar(MAX) NULL,
[column3] varchar(MAX) NULL,
[column4] varchar(MAX) NULL,
[column5] varchar(MAX) NULL
)

BULK INSERT test
FROM 'c:\temp\testimport.txt'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r'
);
```

The really strange thing is that I can use the data import wizard and it imports the data perfectly, without any issue, and handles the lack of tabs for the columns just fine. But I don't know what the wizard is doing behind the scenes to make this happen. I would love to have the code it uses to create the table and do the insert as that would probably answer my question for me. At the end of the day I can't use the wizard as this will eventually be part of an automated task I'll be running against an SQL Server Express database on multiple files with different names but the same column header.

Maybe bulk insert isn't the way to go here? Or there is something obvious I'm missing that someone else might know off the top of their head. Either way, all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

---

As Tim H suggested I've made a few attempts at creating a format file to accommodate the data. Results so far are as follows.

Using
`bcp temp.dbo.test format nul -x -f test_format.xml -n -T`

produces

```
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="column1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="column2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="column3" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="column4" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="column5" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Using this temp file as is produces......

Msg 4866, Level 16, State 7, Line 31
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

My attempt to edit the XML to work.....

```
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="column1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="column2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="column3" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="column4" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="column5" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Which does insert the data, but unfortunately still produces the same jumbled insert with overlapping lines in the same row.

Comment: Can you try with `KEEPNULLS` option? Another option is to use a format file, you can generate a format file first, then use it to import that might work.

Comment: Have already tried KEEPNULLS and the result is the same. As for a format file, I had read about it a bit, but have no experience with it. I just sort of figured if the wizard can pull off the import, there must be a clean way to do it with a query.

Comment: You've tagged both SQL Server *and* MySQL? If that wasn't intentional, please remove one.

Comment: Accidental and removed, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found a direct solution from SQL express for this. I ended up going with PowerShell scripting to solve the problem. Import-CSV pulled the data from the files uniformly and without issue. Not sure why, but it handled the data far better than SQL did. From there I used variables for each line and Invoke-SQLCmd and some SQL scripting to import them into the DB. Worked like a charm. Since this process is all on the local server there aren't any security issues to worry about, so it was an acceptable solution. Thanks again for all the suggestions and help though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the source files? If not, are the width of each column a fixed width or variable width? I know your create table example uses `varchar(max)`'s. The bulk insert feature in SQL Server allows you to use a format file that better defines how the expected input should be formatted, by column, including whether a column is nullable. Microsoft's doc for bulk inserts is actually pretty helpful (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), especially the link at the end of the page to format files.

This page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-nulls-or-use-default-values-during-bulk-import-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) directly deals with null values, which would be your predicament.

Comment: The width of the columns are variable. These are flat files produced by a machine that writes varied data to some of it's columns. Hence why I went with VARCHAR(MAX) so that it could handle anything the machine throws into a column. I could probably get away with VARCHAR(100). At least that's what I did in the wizard. Although I haven't gone through all of the .txt files yet to see if anything would overrun 100. So I was playing it safe.

Comment: What does the ultimate destination of these columns expect? If it expects a field no wider than say 100 characters, then the best choice would be to limit it to a varchar(100) fairly early on so that you're not carrying extra data than what your application will actually use. That still won't by itself solve your current problem, I'll admit. I had a similar issue with a geocoding project I did awhile back. I'm trying to find my code from that to see if I can give you a precise answer for how I overcame it.

Comment: So according to MS, you'll absolutely have to use a format file. From their docs:
"Format files are required if: ...
The data file has a different number of fields that the target table has columns; for example:

- The target table contains at least one column for which either a default value is defined or NULL is allowed."

Comment: For creating the format file try using this in a command line window: ```bcp MyTestDatabase.dbo.test format nul -x -f test_format.xml -n -T``` where "MyTestDatabase.dbo.test" is an example version of the problem table that you have on your local instance of SQL Server, with one or more of the fields containing a null value.

Comment: After creating the format file, using the command `BCP CMM_DATA.dbo.test IN C:\temp\testimport.txt -f testimport.xml -T` produces the following error. `Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Attempt to bulk-copy an oversized column to the SQL Server`

Comment: Same issue when called from SQL.... Using the query `BULK INSERT test   
   FROM 'c:\temp\testimport.txt'   
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'c:\temp\testimport.xml',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r');  
GO  ` produces the error of `Msg 4866, Level 16, State 17, Line 31
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly`

Comment: Also, specifying the field and row terminators in .fmt file will import the data, but unfortunately with the same original flawed result of 2 lines into one row.

Comment: So creating the format file is only the first step. You have to tweak the contents of the generated file in order to get it to a useable state. If I had to guess, the file is only showing 4 columns in the <ROW> entity. If so, you'll need to add the fifth and have it use the same ```xsi:type``` as the other 4 columns. One attribute you'll absolutely have to include in the definition for each column is ```NULLABLE = "YES"```.

Comment: The file is showing 5 columns. I tried editing a few things but am still getting the same types of results regardless of what I change. The problem still being that on the import it seems to ignore the CR/LF and stuff 2 rows into one. I did stumble upon another resource that seems to to have solved the problem, but he unfortunately used a hard coded delimiter in his .exe file, and I'm not sure how to compile the updated version. It auto generates the format file on the fly. https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-import-flat-files-with-a-varying-number-of-columns-in-sql-server/

Comment: Can you post the contents of the format file you currently have?

Comment: The results of both your command to create the format file, and my attempt to edit it have been appended to the original question. Thanks again for help with this by the way, and have a Merry Christmas as well.

Comment: So I dropped your example text file into Notepad++ to see the actual formatting characters involved. Assuming that the third row "4   4   6   4   " includes a null value for the fifth column, the issue appears to be with the second row "2   5   4   6" because it contains no such null value in the fifth column. No matter how good the format file is, SQL isn't going to know what to do here because it doesn't know which column was omitted (could just as easily be column 2 instead of column 5). You will need the source program generating the file to assign a default value for all columns.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for coming back to this. I had forgotten I hadn't closed it out. I ended up going with powershell scripting to solve the problem. Import-CSV pulled the data from the files uniformly and without issue. From there I used variables for each line and Invoke-SQLCmd to import them into the DB. Worked like a charm. Since this process is all on the local server there aren't any security issues to worry about, so it was an acceptable solution. Thanks again for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer would be to add the following to your `BULK INSERT...WITH` statement: `KEEPNULLS`. It does as you would expect: it keeps null values instead of tossing them. The bulk insert utility will toss nulls by default.

Comment: Adding KEEPNULLS to the above bulk import statement still produces the same flawed result.

Comment: So instead of ```ROWTERMINATOR = '\r'```, try ```ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'```.

Comment: \r\n produces zero rows inserted.